# What does the parser expect when throwing a Psych::SyntaxError?

Tags: bundle, yaml

I'm setting up [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org) on my computer (ubuntu). When I try to create a database 
with `bundle exec rake db:create:all`, a syntax error is returned:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (/home/openproject/config/configuration.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 105 column 3
```

And these are lines from 102 to 107. **Note: spaces after line number do not belong to the code.**

```
102 # default configuration options for all environments
103 default:
104   # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
105   email_delivery_method: :smtp
106   perform_deliveries: true
107   smtp_address: smtp.gmail.com
```

What characters is the parser expecting? I must also note you that I'm not **yet** familiar with YAML, ruby or perl (if there are relations to these).

Comment: Looks valid to me; I assume you're using spaces and not tabs?

Comment: Why yes I am. The code I pasted is absolutely the same as in the configuration file, excluding the line numbers and spaces after them.

Comment: Have you tried http://yamllint.com/?

Answer (score 1):

You should post the entire file.

I had this same error occur and I was looking around the line numbers that the error thrown.

Actually, it was much further down the file. Too many spaces before a key name (5 instead of 4).